# A value of type Future<Class> cannot be assigned to an entity of type Class

Tags: dart, future

I want to be able to return a Class in my case the class name is `Car`. I want to return it from my provider to my screen. In my provider i have this method which should return the an object of the class Car `provider.dart`

```
Future<Car> fetchCarById(int carId) async {
  final url =
      'demourl';
  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedCar = json.decode(response.body);
    if (extractedCar == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final Car selectedCar = Car(
        id: extractedCar['ID'],
        brand: extractedCar['Brand'],
        model: extractedCar['Model'],
    final List<Car> loadedProducts = [];
    loadedProducts.add(selectedCar);
    _items = loadedProducts;
    notifyListeners();
    return selectedCar;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

But instead I am getting this error

> A value of type Future cannot be assigned to an entity of type Car

When i try to get the Car object from my screen `screen.dart`

```
final Car car = Cars(auth.token).fetchCarById(carId);
```

I saw it could be done with `FutureBuilder`, but is there a simplify way to do this? I don't want to touch my code in the `screen.dart` file. Is is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method is marked as `async` and does therefore not return `Car` but `Future<Car>`. In you assignment you have set the type to `Car` and there gets the error since there are a type mismatch between the type of the variable and the returned value of the called method.

The returned `Future` indicates that the value are properly not ready and you need to wait for the value. This can be done in a async method by using the `await` keyword:

```
Future<void> method() async {
  final Car car = await Cars(auth.token).fetchCarById(carId);
}
```

Or you can add a callback method which are called when the value is ready:

```
void method() {
  final Car car =
      Cars(auth.token).fetchCarById(carId).then((car) => print(car));
}
```

I recommend you read the documentation about asynchronous programming in Dart: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: how can i call the `method()` after that because when calling `method()` i am again getting the same error

Comment: Some people are talking about asynchronous programming in Dart like a sickness in your code which will spread across your code base. The reason for this is that when you first are going to use async you need to stick to it. Again, I recommend you read the linked page so you understand the reason why async are a concept and how to handle it.